# WP_Comment_Query() displays "password protected" comments?

Tags: comments, wp-comment-query

It appears that looping through [wp_comment_query()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Comment_Query) with the argument `post_status` set to `publish` also lists comments that are posted on *password protected* posts.

Is this the correct behavior or is this a bug? How can I avoid looping through comments submitted to password protected posts?

I checked through the database `wp_comments` table and there doesn't seem to be a relevant entry to play with.

Using the Query Monitor plugin, I was able to inspect the SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_comments JOIN wp_posts
ON wp_posts.ID = wp_comments.comment_post_ID
WHERE ( comment_approved = '1' )
AND wp_posts.post_status IN ('publish')
AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('post')
ORDER BY wp_comments.comment_date_gmt DESC
LIMIT 8
```

To clarify the problem, as it stands, if you use `wp_comment_query()` to display comments (for example in the front-end), then comments that were posted on **password protected** posts are looped through.

Comment: Could you post the code that queries your comments, as well as the resulting SQL statement?

Comment: so `$comments = WP_Comment_Query( array( 'post_status' => 'publish' ) );` give you comments to private posts? Could you post the resulting SQL query?

Comment: You can do it with a plugin like Query Monitor or the Debug Bar series.

Comment: Yeah, so that query makes sure comments are taken for published posts only. Why do you think it's returning comments for private posts as well? Can you `print_r` the returned set and check the post ID's against the database posts table?

Comment: @kovshenin It appears this issue is related to password protected posts, not private posts. That was my mistake. You can test this behavior as well. Simply create a password protected post, post a comment with a specific user and run the following by adding the $user_id... for example: $comments = WP_Comment_Query( array( 'post_status' => 'publish', 'post_author' => $user_id ) );

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a bug (gasp!) really just not provided for. You have to add a filter to do this, eg

```
add_filter( 'comments_clauses', function ( $pieces, $query ) {
    if ( empty( $query->query_vars['wpse_no_password'] ) ) return $pieces;
    global $wpdb;
    $pieces[ 'where' ] .= $wpdb->prepare( ' AND ' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_password = %s', '' );
    return $pieces;
}, 10, 2 );

$args = array( 'post_status' => 'publish', 'wpse_no_password' => 1 );
$query = new WP_Comment_Query( $args );
```

Comment: This is great bonger! IMO this behavior should be considered in core because comment entries in password protected posts should essentially be hidden (private) from a loop unless otherwise requested.

Comment: You have a point, though a quick scan of trac reveals a backend bug https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/25338 that was downgraded to an enhancement (and then slid into the usual trac pit of endless silence...)

Comment: You have some amazing skills finding things in trac. I should invest time searching there prior to asking here. Thanks again!